# Problem running latest version of nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I downloaded latest version of NHibernate “2.1.0.2002”.

It built fine, but when I run my unit tests, I keep getting error :-

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.0.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

It looks like somewhere it looks of old version.

Here is link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839112/problem-while-migrating-nhibernate-to-higher-version

This is internal error  I am getting:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = NHibernate, Version=2.0.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Project Files/CIS3G/Webapp/_Test_DAL/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : CIS3G.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp\_Test_DAL\bin\Debug\_Test_DAL.dll.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: NHibernate, Version=2.0.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Project Files/CIS3G/Webapp/_Test_DAL/bin/Debug/NHibernate.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you set the Specific Version-Property on your NHibernate Reference to 'true'? It doesn't seem to be the case on this error but with new NHibernate you need to provide an external ByteCodeProvider like Linfu.dll as well. Please check this also.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before.

In my case the problem was that I was using a `UnitOfWork` implementation for handling Nhibernate `sessionFactories`.

I've been using this lib for a while so I just copied the compiled dll to a new test project with the new version of NHibernate, so I got the version problem.